# Bootstrap form tag for search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap form tag:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_tag(url: pins_path, method: "get") do |f| %>
    <%= f.search_field :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search restaurants" %>
    <%= f.submit "Search", :name => nil %>
   <% end %>
```

Now I receive the error message:

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)
```

Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your second argument must be a hash, so you should pass value to field using `value` key:

```
<%= f.search_field :search, value: params[:search], placeholder: "Search restaurants" %>
```